# Video editing frameworks for Swift

Tags: swift, video-processing

I am in the process of trying to create an app that focuses on editing video in Swift. I was wondering if there are any video editing frameworks out there for Swift with documentation somewhere? I know that, in Objective-C, there is AVFoundation, but is there an equivalent for Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the import statement to the top of your Swift file to  use it (the same for all frameworks) in this case:

```
import AVFoundation
```